# SciTE can't flush output pane until program exit

Tags: ruby, editor, scite

SciTE version is 2.25.

I have some ruby code to test it.

```
def foo
  puts "hello"
  sleep 5
  puts "world"
end

puts foo
```

SciTE's output pane will show this:

```
>ruby scite.rb
```

And 5 seconds later print:

```
hello
world

>Exit code: 0
```

It's not correct and I remember the previous version SciTE is right. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting `STDOUT.sync = true` at the beginning of your program. I'm neither a Windows nor SciTE user, but I know that some of our students at Rubylearning had similar problems and apparently that was the fix (or manual calls to `flush` after outputting something).

Comment: Thx! it works. why it runs correct in 'irb'? and have anyother beautiful method to solve this? (putting 'that' at the beginning of a program is not cool

Comment: Sorry, as I said I'm not a Windows user, I only happened to know this one because some of our students had the same problem.